# Hide element if span element inside a div tag is empty using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hide an element if the span element inside a div has no text

below is sample HTML

```
<div class="showcase-caption" style="display: block;">
 <span> If this span has no text then i need to change the display property of outer div to none</span>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9Ug/1/)

I tried to do this using css but it didn't work as expected. so i think jquery can work better and handle older browser also.

In this case i need to change the inline property which is generated automatically by other script for showing image caption for image gallery.

**Update**:
Thank you guys for your replies. I am choose 'satpal' solution as it is short & gave me exact result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use **[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector)**. You don't need if block.

```
$('.showcase-caption span:empty').parent().hide()
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WPf5f/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) along with [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector to accomplish your task,

```
if($('.showcase-caption span').is(':empty')) {
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9Ug/2/)

Full code:

```
var cache = $('.showcase-caption');
if($('span', cache).is(':empty')) {
  cache.hide();
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9Ug/7/)

---

Or you can simply write by using the `:has()` selector,

```
$('.showcase-caption:has(span:empty)').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9Ug/11/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bv9Ug/10/)

Use jQuery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and **[`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector)** pseudo selector.

```
if( $('.showcase-caption span').is(':empty') ) {
    $('.showcase-caption').hide();
}
```

Comment: It still show the green bar due to padding i want to hide it completey

Comment: @sudharsan, in my demo i had written `hide()` code on `span` click. So used `this`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".showcase-caption span").html().trim().length <= 0 ){
            $(".showcase-caption").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$(function){
    if($('.showcase-caption span').is(':empty')){
        $('.showcase-caption').css("display" , "none");
    }

    }
```